# Log in to server after mistakingly having changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config 16.04

Tags: ssh

Everything was working fine, but I was getting tired of always having to ssh in to my server (ubuntu 16.04 on openstack) after having a cup of coffe. So I searched and found that I could set `ServerAliveInterval 60` and `ServerAliveCountMax 1200`. After appending these changes to the  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and rebooting, the server is refusing my connection on port 22. I have now found that these changes should have been made to `~/.ssh/config`.

Now--the big question- How can I connect to the server to change this? Is it at all possible?

Comment: What is your server hosting type? a VPS or dedicated server?

Comment: See edit above-- I´m trying to ssh into an openstack instance running ubuntu 16.04 server

Comment: Depending on where that OpenStack instance is, you may be able to rescue it by making another instance, mounting the original instance's hard drive inside that, and removing the lines in `/mountpoint/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directives you were trying to add are for clients, not the server. Therefore you should have edited local `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` files instead of the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Because you now have directives that will not be understood by the openssh-server, it will not start. Example:

```
...
--
-- Unit ssh.service has begun starting up.
Jan 22 10:46:25 s15 sshd[18079]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 91: Bad configuration option: ServerAliveInterval
Jan 22 10:46:25 s15 sshd[18079]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 92: Bad configuration option: ServerAliveCountMax
Jan 22 10:46:25 s15 sshd[18079]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
Jan 22 10:46:25 s15 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 22 10:46:25 s15 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
-- Subject: Unit ssh.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit ssh.service has failed.
--
...
```

For future reference, a suggestion is to re-start the service rather than re-boot:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

Why? Because then you might not lose your current SSH session (I did not lose mine just now, but I am unable to establish a new connection) and you have a possibility to recover from a mistake.

To answer your actual questions:

"How can I connect to the server to change this?" You can not, at least not via ssh.

"Is it at all possible?" Not via ssh. I do not know if you have other connection options.

Comment: I know--tough way to find out... Hopefully I´ve learnt by now..